# how to make navbar full width

Tags: html, css

I would like to have my navbar stretch to the edges of the browser. I can do that by specifying the width by pixel but when I make width="100%" it is not working + it shows scroll bar at the bottom.....so how can I make it stretch to the window size of the browser horizontally?

**Here is the** [Demo](http://www.henny.bugs3.com/test.php/)

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">


body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#nav {
    float: left;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #121314;
    border-top: 1px solid #2b2e30;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;

}

#nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

#nav ul li {
    float:left;
}

#nav ul li a {
    float: left;
    color:#d4d4d4;
    padding: 15px 97px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#3C4042;
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(59,63,65)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(72,76,77)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(75,77,77)) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
    background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}




#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li:hover > a {
    color: red;
    background:#3C4042;
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
    background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 -1px #000;

}

#nav li ul a:hover, 
#nav ul li li:hover > a  {
color: #2c2c2c;
    background: #5C9ACD;
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.17, rgb(61,111,177)), color-stop(0.51, rgb(80,136,199)), color-stop(1, rgb(92,154,205)) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
    background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    border-top: 1px solid #7BAED9;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}



 #nav li:hover ul {
    left: auto;
}




#nav li li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav" > 
<ul > 
<li width="300px" ><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Sell</a> 

<li><a href="#">Services</a> 

<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Sign In/Register</a></li> 
</ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quess you try to style 'ul li a' instead of 'ul li' elements. As someone mentioned above give to each li element 20%, style everything with 'box-sizing: border-box' and you're ready to go ;)
Here you can see solution: http://codepen.io/czaras/pen/Auqtn

Comment: very nice but how can I make when the mouse is over  highlight the whole cell?

Comment: also on firefox Sign In/register goes to the next row but it works on chrome&safari...the css doesn't show on IE 9

Answer (score 3):

The width specifies the width of the content. The padding and border sizes are added to that specified width. If you want it *including the border* to be 100%, you must remove your border.

See this illustration:

```
 _______________________
|  margin               |
|  ___________________  |
| |  border           | |
| |  _______________  | |
| | |  padding      | | |
| | |  ___________  | | |
| | | |  content  | | | |
| | | |___________| | | |
| | | |           | | | |
| | | |<- width ->| | | |
| | |_______________| | |
| |___________________| |
|_______________________|
```

Comment: I removed the border and added width:100%; on nav but getting the same thing

Comment: Removing the border on `#nav` removes the scrollbar for me.

Answer (score 1):

just make margin of body 0%

`body{ margin: 0%; }`

Answer (score 0):

`#nav` is 100% width, but the individual buttons aren't taking up the space you want because they are conforming to the width of their text (`width:auto`). The simplest way to get the effect you are looking for (for any number of buttons) is to use a `table` with a 100% width. A more complicated way is to give each button an equal percentage width such that with the number of buttons it adds up to 100%. You have 5 buttons, so you can put `width:20%;` on `#nav ul li`. You'll also want to eliminate the large 97px left-right padding you have on this style and choose a much smaller value.

To deal with the scroll bar on the bottom, specify `box-sizing: border-box;` on `#nav`.

Comment: Do be aware of [what browsers support `box-sizing`](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) if you need to support older browsers, though.

Comment: try to avoid using tables for layout purposes. not wrong, but I believe times have changed. http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com/

Comment: @MagnaMaster Likely you need to set your 97px padding to something much smaller (say 4px). You'll also need to move some of your styles to the proper place, your backgrounds belong on the `li` instead of the `a`, and you may want to apply `text-align:center` to the `#nav ul li` as it seems you want centered text.

Comment: @MagnaMaster The width will be 20%. Right now you're getting your width from the padding, but the goal is to get it from the 20% instead. Just be sure your styles are in the right place. The background gradient and some of the other styles are now being applied on the inline element (`a`) instead of the container (`li`).